# Truth values in the “worldly-successive” levels of $V$

Tags: set-theory

Assume that the theory “ZFC + there is a proper class of worldly cardinals” is consistent and use this theory as the background set theory.

Let $f(\alpha)$ denote the $\alpha$-th worldy cardinal. Does there exist a statement $\phi$ (a finite formula of arbitrary complexity) such that the truth value of $\phi$ in $V_{f(\alpha)}$ is different from the truth value of $\phi$ in $V_{f(\alpha + 1)}$? If yes (or no), is it possible to prove it?

Comment: If $\alpha=\sup\alpha$ then "There is a largest worldly cardinal" holds in $V_{f(\alpha +1)}$ but not in $V_{f(\alpha)}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: what does “$\alpha=\sup\alpha$” mean? An ordinal which is the supremum of itself?

Comment: Let $P(\phi, \alpha)$ mean $V_{f(\alpha)} \models \phi \land V_{f(\alpha + 1)} \nvDash \phi$. Which of these statements are you asking about? (1) $\exists \phi \forall \alpha P(\phi, \alpha)$ (2) $\exists \phi \exists \alpha P(\phi, \alpha)$ (3) $\forall \alpha \exists \phi P(\phi, \alpha)$

Comment: @MarkSaving: it seems that (2) is what I am asking about.

Comment: @lyricallywicked (2) is trivial. Let $\phi$ be the statement “there are no worldly cardinals”. Then $\phi$ holds in $V_{f(0)}$ but not in $V_{f(1)}$.

Comment: @MarkSaving: maybe the following question needs a separate post, but does there exist a statement $\phi$ that satisfies both of the following properties? (i) there are unboundedly many ordinals such that for any such $\alpha$ we have $V_{f(\alpha)} \models \phi \land V_{f(\alpha + 1)} \nvDash \phi;$ (ii) there are unboundedly many ordinals such that for any such $\beta$ we have $V_{f(\beta)} \nvDash \phi \land V_{f(\beta + 1)} \models \phi.$

Comment: @lyricallywicked Let $\phi$ be the statement “there is a largest worldly cardinal, but not a second-largest worldly cardinal”. Then $V_{f(\gamma)}$ holds iff $\gamma$ can be written as $\eta + 1$ and $\eta$ is not a successor ordinal. So for any limit ordinal $\beta$, we have $V_{f(\beta)} \nvDash \phi$, $V_{f(\beta + 1)} \models \phi$, and $V_{f(\beta + 2)} \nvDash \phi$. Thus, $\phi$ satisfies both your conditions.

Comment: If $x$ is a set of ordinals then the ordinal $\sup x=\cup x$ is the lub for the members of $x$. If $x$ is an ordinal then $x$ is also a set of ordinals, and for an ordinal $x$ with no largest member we have $x=\sup x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very strong example of the phenomenon you're asking about.

There is a formula $\nu$ such that, for each ordinal $\eta$, $\nu^{V_\eta}$ is the ordinal corresponding to the ordertype of the set of worldly cardinals $<\eta$. Now consider the formula $\varphi\equiv$ "$\nu$ is even" (an ordinal $x$ is even iff $x=2y$ for some ordinal $y$). Then $\varphi$ "alternates truth values" as we climb up the worldly cardinals: it is true in $V_{f(\lambda)}$ for each limit ordinal $\lambda$ (including $0$), and for each ordinal $\alpha$ we have $$V_{f(\alpha)}\models\varphi\quad\iff\quad V_{f(\alpha+1)}\models\neg\varphi.$$

Comment: Is it consistent that $f(\alpha)=\cup_{\beta<\alpha}f(\beta)$ for some $\alpha$? In such a case, since $f(\alpha)$ is singular but satisfies ZFC (especially Replacement), wouldn't that cause difficulties with the relativization of $\nu$ to $V_{f(\alpha)}$?  I think you can side-step this by saying $\varphi\equiv$  "$\nu$ is even or there is no ordinal upper bound  for worldly cardinals".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That can happen (as far as we know), e.g. if $\alpha$ is inaccessible. (Note that $f(\alpha)$ need **not** be singular!) I wouldn't really call this an issue, though, it's just a point where you have to be a bit careful about how you precisely write $\varphi$. You've described one fix, there are others (e.g. "$\nu$ has no greatest element or $\nu=\lambda+2n$ for some limit $\lambda$ and some finite $n$").

Comment: I was mistaken about the def'n of worldly cardinal.